# how to implement swf address navigation in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I want to implment swf address navigation in struts 2 like twitter and facebook navigation. I meant to say for each page user navigation header and footer and some common components across the websites will not be loaded for each user navigation. in some sites like twitter and facebook they have done with swf address implementation by concatinating '#' to current url for each user navigation with required pagename.so i want to implement same thing in struts 2. So how can i implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "swf" navigation; I only know swf as Flash, which neither Twitter nor Facebook use for navigation.

*Why* do you want a "#" in the URL? What do you think it does?

In any case, if what you're asking is really "How do I get only some parts of the UI to update during navigation", the answer is either Ajax, or iframes. (Personally, I think iframes are almost always wrong, especially with what modern JavaScript and CSS allow, but they have their uses.)

Comment: Dave Newton:swf address navigation means its a third party javascript library to support user page navigation through ajax most of the times. Except some cases it is the page refresh. But for this there must be server support to identify which is page refresh and component refresh. Even when component refresh happened still user can use back button enabled. Normally through ajax it can't

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am not sure about the term *SWF Address Navigation*. *Hash Bookmarking* is a more common phrase for libraries that actually does this task.

This is a matter of client side programming and it has nothing to do with struts 2. There is a good jQuery plugin for that. It is called [jQuery history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/).

You can find lots of other libraries and the best choice depends on your application requirements.